# Diseño personalizado Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

quisiera saber como hacer un diseño en especifico.
Estoy haciendo la web con html y Bootstrap y no se como hacer este diseño de aquí, tanto la imagen y el texto encima con texto a la derecha, que sea responsive. Sin las estrellas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No eh probado nada mas que:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="img.jgp" alt="alternative">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pero ya no se que como hacer lo que acabo de mencionar :(. Espero su ayuda, gracias!!!!

Comment: Podrías agregar que has intentado por favor?

Comment: Eh intentado lo que sale ahi, que es lo basico, pero agrego margin-left:-15px al contenido del texto, pero nada :(

Comment: creo que podrias utilizar un [Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) Aunque pienso que tambien podria quedar bien una [card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) con la imagen arriba y la informacion abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo así
Es algo simple, si te es de utilidad, define los estilos responsive

Recuerda copiar el codigo y probarlo en tu ordenador por cuestión de las referencias a los archivos de bootstrap...
Si te es de utilidad puedes agregar los estilos ya en tu archivo externo yo lo hice solo a modo de prueba... igual utilice una imagen de internet, puedes probar con una imagen que tengas local si gustas...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-light p-5" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
    <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2019/07/origen-nombres-informatica-nunca-hubieras-imaginado_2.jpg?itok=s-Z9jTJv" width="75%">
    <div class="bg-white p-4 font-weight-bold" style="position: absolute; top: 25%; right: 10%; width: 35%; border-radius: 10px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe debitis consequuntur totam odio laudantium recusandae numquam esse sit laboriosam earum exercitationem alias maiores, voluptatum quae quo itaque delectus dignissimos! Tenetur.
      <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto btn-block w-auto mt-2">Pedir yo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos

Comment: Gracias bro! si me funciono